# `ng build` skipping/not emitting components for Angular 6 library .d.ts files (type definitions not being generated for some components)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-components, angular-library

I am trying to get an Angular 6+ component library published for a work project, and have run into a suspicious issue that seems like a compiler bug.

This is the source code repository, but I have included code below demonstrating the issue as well.

https://github.com/bradkovach/porcelain/tree/master/projects/porcelain/src

The project was generated with `ng generate library` and is theoretically now ready to push to npm. Whenever I run `ng build porcelain`, the project builds with no errors, but the compiled result is missing type definitions for two components `SimpleRefinerComponent` and `DateRefinerComponent`. I found the following [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196878/ng-build-does-not-include-component-class-code-of-library-modules), which appeared to suffer from the same issue, but the stated solution did not work for me.

I have built the project on a separate machine using these commands...

```
git clone git@github.com:bradkovach/porcelain.git
npm install
ng build porcelain
```

This is what the `public_api.ts` file at `projects/porcelain/src/public_api.ts` looks like...

```
/**
 * Porcelain exposed components.
 */

export { PorcelainModule } from './lib/porcelain.module';
export { PorcelainComponent } from './lib/porcelain.component';

export { SimpleRefinerModule } from './lib/simple-refiner/simple-refiner.module';
export { SimpleRefinerComponent } from './lib/simple-refiner/simple-refiner.component';

export { DateRefinerModule } from './lib/date-refiner/date-refiner.module';
export { DateRefinerComponent } from './lib/date-refiner/date-refiner.component';

export { RefinersModule } from './lib/refiners/refiners.module';
export { RefinersComponent } from './lib/refiners/refiners.component';

export * from './lib/refiners/IOption';
export * from './lib/refiners/IOptions';
export * from './lib/refiners/IRefiner';
export * from './lib/refiners/IRefinerValue'
```

When I run `ng build` it builds the following public_api.d.ts file...

```
/**
 * Porcelain exposed components.
 */
export { PorcelainModule } from './lib/porcelain.module';
export { PorcelainComponent } from './lib/porcelain.component';
export { SimpleRefinerModule } from './lib/simple-refiner/simple-refiner.module';
export { SimpleRefinerComponent } from './lib/simple-refiner/simple-refiner.component';
export { DateRefinerModule } from './lib/date-refiner/date-refiner.module';
export { DateRefinerComponent } from './lib/date-refiner/date-refiner.component';
export { RefinersModule } from './lib/refiners/refiners.module';
export { RefinersComponent } from './lib/refiners/refiners.component';
export * from './lib/refiners/IOption';
export * from './lib/refiners/IOptions';
export * from './lib/refiners/IRefiner';
export * from './lib/refiners/IRefinerValue';
```

The `SimpleRefinerComponent` and `DateRefinerComponent` exports are reporting the following errors, respectively

- `Cannot find module './lib/simple-refiner/simple-refiner.component'.ts(2307)`
- `Cannot find module './lib/date-refiner/date-refiner.component'.ts(2307)`

I have tried

- [Aforementioned StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196878/ng-build-does-not-include-component-class-code-of-library-modules)
- Delete and re-install `node_modules`
- Cloning a fresh instance of the project
- Updating to most-recent `@angular/*@^6.0.0` and latest `@angular-devkit/*` packages.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently having this problem as well, by any chance do you remember what was the fix, if it was fixable? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to rebuild the project.  I ended up deleting everything and rebuilding one component at a time.

Comment: Ouch, my problem was easier to fix than that, after nearly crying for not understanding why the `ng build` was not generating half of my project, I tried again in Incognito ... it worked, damned Chrome cached the application's routing and it tried to access components that did not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue -- I had two components clearly exported via the `public-api.ts` file, but no `component-one.component.d.ts` or `component-two.component.d.ts` files were getting generated in the `dist` directory with `ng build.`

My problem turned out to be that I needlessly had a `private` keyword on one of the methods of a class that that both `ComponentOne` and `ComponentTwo` extended. Once I removed `private`, the `.d.ts` files were generated.