# ng build prod missing lazy loaded child module

Tags: angular

A newly added feature module that is set to lazily load isn't being included when I run `ng build --prod`.  However, it is included and loaded correctly when run locally using `ng serve`.  The project uses Angular 5.2.10.

I'm fairly new to Angular, and I'm not sure where to look for configuration problems.  I've read the following:

- https://v5.angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
- https://v5.angular.io/guide/entry-components
- [ng build does not include component class code of library modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51196878/1459580)

I've also compared the newly added feature module line-by-line with other existing modules that do route and bundle correctly.  I can't find anything obvious that is missing.

Here's the route to the feature module:

```
  {
    path: "admin/audit",
    loadChildren: "app/features/audit/audit.module#AuditModule",
    data: { title: "Audit Logs" }
  },
```

Here are the routes inside the feature module's routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AuditListComponent,
  runGuardsAndResolvers: "paramsOrQueryParamsChange",
  resolve: {
    pageResult: AuditListResolverService
  }
}];
```

What are some other things I should check?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my browser was caching the site.  The build and deploy was, in fact, working correctly and as expected.

Moral of the story: always try clearing your cache.  I knew that, but it's late here...

Comment: by using view page source in browser, check your `index.html` file and re-confirm that files which are includes in `index.html` are with hashing in their names or not. because when angular create a build, it generate hashes with file names according to changes in file which are really helpful for cache bursting method after new deployment..